# how can I get the median and sd of each column?

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(Mydata = c("AAA_F1", "AAA_F2", "AAA_F3"), F1_100 = c(0, 
7611.5, 12257.1), F2_100 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), F3_100 = c(200, 1967.7, 
400), F1_200M = c(0, 8155.4, 0), F2_200M = c(100, 500, 2490.1
), F3_200M = c(0, 2395.3, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I am trying to get the median and sd as two data frames, I am doing the following but I dont get what I want so, the first line should give me the median of each 3 values from each column
and the second must give the standard deviation of each three values of each column. I thought I must group them with the naming

```
df_median <- as.data.frame(df %>% group_by(Mydata) %>% summarise_all(funs(median)))
df_sd <- as.data.frame(df %>% group_by(Mydata) %>% summarise_all(funs(sd)))
```

The output should look like this for instance for median (I used xls)

```
Mydata  F1_100  F2_100  F3_100  F1_200M F2_200M F3_200M
AAA     7611.5.     0     400      0       500    0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sapply` in base R:

```r
sapply(df[-1], median)
#R>  F1_100  F2_100  F3_100 F1_200M F2_200M F3_200M 
#R>  7611.5     0.0   400.0     0.0   500.0     0.0 
sapply(df[-1], sd)
#R>   F1_100   F2_100   F3_100  F1_200M  F2_200M  F3_200M 
#R> 6188.067    0.000  968.026 4708.522 1280.174 1382.927
```

You can use `lapply` instead followed by `as.data.frame` if you want a `data.frame`.

Comment: it adds X into the column name

Comment: It does not when I run `as.data.frame(lapply(df[-1], median))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `across` to apply multiple functions to multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>% summarise(across(c(F1_100:F3_200M), list(median = median, sd = sd)))
```

Comment: I gave an example above , they should be separated

Comment: Do you want to apply the functions separately? `df1 <- df %>% summarise(across(c(F1_100:F3_200M), median))` and `df2 <- df %>% summarise(across(c(F1_100:F3_200M), sd))`

Comment: I get error because I removed the characters as being column names, any idea ? I like your solution but still not working

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What do you mean? Is your data different than what you have shared?